# Working out what pages are giving Access Denied

Tags: permissions, access-denied, web-analytics

I am checking out my Top Pages in central admin for my site. Looking at this I can see that the top page is /_layouts/accessdenied.aspx. Ideally I want to work our why that is so high. Can I find out what is causing people to get directed to this page. Is it a bad configuration of permissions on my part or people going to the wrong section.